# Uploading folder from local system to a perticular folder in S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

What should I change in my code so that I can upload my entire folder from local system to a particular folder present in my s3 bucket.

```py
import os
import boto3

s3_resource = boto3.resource("s3", region_name="ap-south-1")

def upload_objects():
    try:
        bucket_name = "<S3 bucket-name>" 
        root_path = '<local folder path>' 
        bucket_folder = '<S3 folder name>'

        my_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
        # s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

        for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root_path):
            path = path.replace("\\","/")
            directory_name = path.replace(root_path,"")
            for file in files:
                my_bucket.upload_file(os.path.join(path, file), directory_name+'/'+file)
     except Exception as err:
        print(err)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    upload_objects()
```

Comment: You haven't explained what's wrong with the code? Any errors?

Comment: No, I'm not getting any errors, but it just simply uploads all the folder contents in the bucket. So, how can I choose a folder inside which I can place the local folder as it is. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using your `bucket_folder` at all. This should be the beginning of your [S3 prefix](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-prefixes.html) as in the S3 there are no folders. Its all about key names and prefixes.

So it should be something as the following:

```
my_bucket.upload_file(os.path.join(path, file), bucket_folder + '/' + directory_name+'/'+file)
```

Comment: Great, it worked. But when I try to have the same sub-folder as my local one instead of '/',  inside my main s3 folder, it just adds folder name to prefix of the file name.
What should I do?
This is what I did =
 my_bucket.upload_file(os.path.join(path, file), bucket_folder + '<folder name>' + directory_name + '/' + file)

Comment: @KartikeyaKawadkar Glad that it worked. You can't do anything about the "adds folder name", as this is how S3 works. If this is undesired, then you can't use S3. Check AWS EFS instead. There are no folders in S3, as I wrote in the answer. Also the python code worked, acceptance of my answer of it would be appreciated.